# Is it useful to use Material Ui in react native app

Tags: reactjs, react-native

> I am developing an app using react native. 
>   Should I use material UI in it? Or any other react components can I use in it?

```
npm install @material-ui/core
yarn add @material-ui/core
```

Comment: This post appears to be [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) as per *Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.*

Comment: If you are asking about that library in particular, no that library does not work on React-Native, so you'd have to find a different one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yah there is good options for design in react native,
react-native-paper is good and Cross-platform Material Design for React Native

```
npm i react-native-paper
```

follow there documentation : https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/index.html